# hql conditional expressions in aggregate functions

Tags: nhibernate, hql, aggregate-functions

Does HQL support conditional expressions in aggregate functions?

I would like to do something like this

```
select
  o.id, 
  count(o),
  count(o.something is null and o.otherthing = :other)
from objects o
```

But I get a MissingTokenException from the Antlr parser.

**EDIT:** By using a subquery it's working, but it's ugly as I'm grouping by several variables...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use expressions in HQL. For this instance, you'll want to use SUM instead of COUNT as follows:

```
select
  o.id, 
  count(o),
  sum(case when o.something is null and o.otherthing = :other then 1 else 0 end)
from objects o
```

When the conditionals match, the SUM will receive a 1 for that row. When they do not match, it'll receive a zero. This should provide the same functionality as a COUNT.